# void animation for component in ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, animation

I have a list of items and I am using a custom component to display them. I want these items to animate in when they are added and animate out when they are removed. Animating in seems to work fine, but when I try to animate them out they disappear immediately. I think this is because the animation property is on an element in the component, but it also does not work if I add the animation property to the component element either.

```
animations = [
  trigger('appear', [
    state('void', style({ height: 0, opacity: 0.2 })),
    transition('void => *', animate(200, style({ height: '*', opacity: 1 }))),
    transition('* => void', animate(200)),
  ])
];

// Custom Component
@Component({
  animations,
  selector: 'bf-post',
  template: `
  <li style="overflow: hidden" [@appear] (click)="deleteItem.emit(item.id)">
    {{item.text}}
  </li>
`,
})
export class PostComponent {
  @Input() item;
  @Output() deleteItem = new EventEmitter;
}

// Using custom component, items is an array of the posts
<ul *ngIf="items.length" [class]="wallCss">
  <bf-post *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item"
    (deleteItem)="deleteItem($event)"></bf-post>
</ul>

  deleteItem(id) {
    const idx = this.items.findIndex(item => id === item.id);
    this.items = [
      ...this.items.slice(0, idx),
      ...this.items.slice(idx + 1),
    ];
  }
```

The `li` does animate in properly whenever an item is added to `items`. However, when I `deleteItem` to remove one of the items, it disappears instantly.

I have also tried using `<bf-post [@appear]`, but this does not animate at all ... the animation styles probably have to be on the `li`. It *does* seem like it waits for the animation to complete before actually removing the element, though.

Is there any way to properly animate the void state of an element rendered inside of an `ngFor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entering and leaving animations has a bug if you try to Detach an item using a method.
(The component is actually getting detached before the animations have a chance to run).
<sub>More about the [Bug/issue reported](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10520) on GitHub here</sub>

---

You need to use host animation binding to see the animation of the component leaving.
<sub>More about [Host Metadata property](https://angular.io/api/core/Component) for Component decorator here</sub>

---

Accordingly, you need to change the code as below:

```
animations : [
  trigger('appear', [
    state('*', style({ height: 0, opacity: 0.2 })),
    transition('void => *', animate(200, style({ height: '*', opacity: 1 }))),
    transition('* => void', animate(200)),
  ])
];

// Custom Component
@Component({
  animations,
  selector: 'bf-post',
  host: { 
     '[@appear]':'true'
  }
  template: `
  <li style="overflow: hidden" (click)="deleteItem.emit(item.id)">
    {{item.text}}
  </li>
`,
})
export class PostComponent {
  @Input() item;
  @Output() deleteItem = new EventEmitter;
}
.........
```

<sub>Parts of code omitted to avoid confusion</sub>

- Notice the change of `[@appear]` binding in the Custom Template and
  addition of one more `host` metadata property.
- Also you might need to change the `state` property in animations to `*` rather than `void` <sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Citation needed | Not sure.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work ... when I use `host` it seems like the `li` are not removed until after the animation is over, but no animation is actually done (in or out). I've also still tried adding `[@appear]` to the `li` as well ... that does work for animating in but re: animating out the same thing happens. It waits until the animation timer is over before removing the item, but it doesn't do any actual animation.

Comment: Hmm That's odd. Also, do you have css-style `display:block`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147867/discussion-between-manubhargav-and-explosion-pills).

Comment: On what? the `li` have `display: list-item`. There is no `display` on the host element, `bf-post` although the animation styles do seem to be applying to that instead.

Comment: Just noting that generally this does work, but with my code I end up with an invalid arrangement of `<bf-post><li></li></bf-post>` so the CSS does not work as expected. Also adding `display: block` to the component may be necessary depending on the animation being done.